# PHP get_headers sometime return Location as array

Tags: php

i can't understand why, sometimes

```
$headers = @get_headers($url , true);
```

return the `Location` field as array instead string....

So if I need to get full url, when it is a string, i'll do

```
$unshorted_url = $headers['Location'];
```

but when `Location` return as array, i don't know what index I need to consider...

Any suggest? and more important..... why `Location` sometime return as array?

I see this "problem" when I try to get an ebay url like this one `https://ebay.us/JOBBf0`

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php#120075

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the URL redirected and the new target is also redirected, we get the Locations in array and we also get the HTTP codes in a number indexed values.

Let's imagine this redirection chain:

`/index.php?id=1` -> `/index.php?id=2` -> `/index.php?id=3`

Location would be:

```
[Location] => Array
    (
        [0] => /index.php?id=2
        [1] => /index.php?id=3
    )
```

the `id=3` would be the landing page.

If you want the first redirect (`id=2` in the example):

```
$headers = get_headers($url, true);

if (is_array($headers['Location'])) {
    $unshorted_url = reset($headers['Location']);
} else {
    $unshorted_url = $headers['Location'];
}
```

And you could use `end()` instead of `reset()` in case you wanted the landing page instead.

Comment: ah ok... no, really i want the more complex link at index 0

Comment: I've updated the answer with both cases (the first redirect and the landing page)

Comment: Thankyou. Very usefull your example!